# How to run class from command line using python file.py?

Tags: python, linux, class, terminal

When I run the script `filename.py` by the command `python filename.py`, it does not prompt for input or print the output.

What command do I have to run to run the code of the class `Base1`?

```py
class Base(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
       #prompts for input
       ......

class Base1(Base):
    def base1(self):
        print('.......')
        return x

    def base2(self): 
        output = Base1.base1(self)
        print(output)
```

Answer (score 10):

Your program must include some statements at the top level (i.e. not indented) that will be executed when your program is run on the command line.

```
class Base(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
       #prompts for inpt
       ......

class Base1(Base):

    def base1(self):
        print('.......')
        return x

    def base2(self): 
        output = Base1.base1(self)
        print(output)

# These commands will be executed when "python filename.py" is run from a shell
foo = Base1()
foo.base1()
....
```

Answer (score 10):

What qwrrty suggested will work, but I would suggest putting it in a main function which in python is done by

```
def main():
    foo = Base1()
    foo.base1()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```